# Portaudio: open file instead of using the microphone

Tags: c, macos, portaudio

I am using PortAudio, and this is how I'm opening a stream for reading right now.

```
Pa_OpenDefaultStream(&stream, 1, 0, paFloat32, SAMPLE_RATE, SAMPLES, PaCallback, NULL);
```

As far as I know, this uses the microphone as input. How can I instead use a file as input? The `Pa_OpenStream` function strangely doesn't seem to let me enter a filename?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PortAudio is for device I/O only, such as speakers, microphones, line inputs and similar devices. To do file I/O you need another library designed for that. For example, [libsoundfile](http://www.mega-nerd.com/libsndfile/), [libsox](http://sox.sourceforge.net/libsox.html) or [libaudiofile](http://audiofile.68k.org/).

Comment: Ah, I see. I guess I misunderstood what PortAudio is for.